# Can not access my spring boot application by url

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I try to access my endpoint with local host url - http://localhost:8080/all
this is my Application.java file

```
package com.example.MyApplication;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication .class, args);
    }

}
```

and this is my end point

```
@RestController("GetAll")
@RequestMapping("/all")
public class GetAll {
    private final DataService dataService;

    @Autowired
    public GetAll (DataService dataService) {
        this.dataService = dataService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<DataDto> getAll() {
        return dataService.getAll();
    }
}
```

and I try with this url - http://localhost:8080/all

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-10-06T15:27:18.574+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "path": "/all"
}
```

Comment: This looks quite different from https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/ . Your class name `GetAll` with two methods `getAll` and `GetAll` seem both weird and clumsy. IMO

Comment: `getAll` is the method, `GetAll` is the constructor. Maybe add a single `/` at the `@GetMapping` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem might happen due to some **components(like controller, service, etc) not being scanned** by spring due to components and the Main class being in a different package. Here, Your main class is in `com.example.MyApplication` package. So If you keep all other components(like controller, service, etc) of the spring boot in the same package or sub-package then that will work as expected. If you want to keep those in the different packages you need to mention those different packages which are having spring components like controllers in the `@ComponentScan` annotation.

Change `GetAll` class's package declaration if you can keep them in the same package:

```
package com.example.MyApplication;

@RestController("GetAll")
@RequestMapping("/all")
public class GetAll {
    private final DataService dataService;

    @Autowired
    public GetAll (DataService dataService) {
        this.dataService = dataService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<DataDto> getAll() {
        return dataService.getAll();
    }
}
```

Reference:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning